# how to redirect to url.com/wp-admin if url.com/admin is typed in?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, redirect

How would I create a wordpress function that will redirect a user to myurl.com/wp-admin if they type in myurl.com/admin?

I would like to have this as a wordpress function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [admin page redirect](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52114/admin-page-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook into `template_redirect`, inspect the request URI, and redirect to the return value of `admin_url()`.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    $request = untrailingslashit( strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );

    if ( 'admin' === $request )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit;
    }
});
```

Note: always use `admin_url()` and the other built-in URL functions, because they will take care of the proper scheme (`https` or `http`).

Comment: That didnt seem to work.

Comment: actually there must be something preventing it from working on the site i tried. I did it on another and it worked