# How to redirect one admin URL to another when admin page URL has "/admin.php?page=" in it?

Tags: admin-menu, wp-redirect

The following code (from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214439/130220), middle section chopped out) allows me to redirect users who land on a certain page in the WP admin to another admin page...

```
function admin_redirects() {
    global $pagenow;

    /* Redirect Customizer to Theme options */
    if($pagenow == 'customize.php'){
        wp_redirect(admin_url('/admin.php?page=theme_options', 'http'), 301);
        exit;
    }

}

add_action('admin_init', 'admin_redirects');
```

It works great...for some pages. The problem is I cannot get redirects to work for pages originating with a URL structure such as "admin.php?page=example-options." The example-options string is just a plugin I was working on, but I think you get the idea. I have tried a lot of variations and other things at this point, but nothing is working. Am I missing something?

Comment: where are you setting `$pagenow` ?

Comment: Just to make sure i understood: 1) you want something like `admin.php?page=example-options` to redirect users to `admin.php?page=theme_options` 2) will there be any kind of role condition, i.e. non-admin users are redirected but admins can access the page ?

Comment: @CelsoBessa Yes, I want to be able to do something like redirect something like admin.php?page=example-options to another page, as opposed to redirecting from something like customize.php to another page. I already came up with the role condition but omitted it from this code as it is not relevant to the core of the problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will achieve what you want by using `[get_current_screen()][1]` and reading the properties from [WP_Screen](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/) object returned as needed.  In your case, I think you will need `$screen->base` or maybe `$screen->id`. According to [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen):

> id  (string) The unique ID of the screen

and

> base  (string) The base type of the screen. For example, for a page 'post-new.php' the base is 'post'.

As an examples, the Yoast SEO Dashboard resides on admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard and the `$screen->base property` for this page is '`toplevel_page_wpseo_dashboard`'

Below you will find an example taken from something i worked some weeks time ago.

```
/**
 * Disallow Admin pages for non-superadmin users on current_screen hook.
 * A fallback for when restricting access is not possible by manage_admin_access_on_init
 *
 * @since    0.1.0
 */
public function wpse_283875_manage_admin_access_on_screen() {
    // a list of restricted pages base properties from get_current_screen
    $restricted_screens = array(
        'formularios_page_gf_help',
        'toplevel_page_genesis',
        'genesis_page_genesis-translations',
        'genesis_page_genesis-import-export',
        'genesis_page_genesis-simple-edits',
        'media_page_wp-smush-bulk',
    );
    // get current screen
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    // if there's no $screen object, we are in customizer, bail out
    if ( is_null($screen) ){
        return;
    }
    // get screen->base
    $screen_base = $screen->base;

    // compare screen->base with each restricted screen
    foreach ($restricted_screens as $restricted_screen) {


        // if user can't manage network and screen base is restricted
        if (!current_user_can('manage_network') && $screen_base == $restricted_screen) {
            //get out!
            wp_redirect(admin_url());
            // stop execution
            exit;
        }

    }
}
// hook to current_screen action with priority 5 to execut ASAP
add_action('current_screen','manage_admin_access_on_screen', 5);
```

If you need to check the screen object, you could use something like this in development environment and read the HTML source:

```
function debug_admin_screen(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    echo '<!--<pre>' . print_r($screen, TRUE) . '</pre>-->';
}
add_action('current_screen', 'debug_admin_screen', 100);
```